# Adding flash message when the user is redirected to login page in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have a simple Symfony2 application that requires the user to be authenticated to see some pages.

When a protected page is visited while anonymous, the user is redirected to the login page. This is all working as expected, but I would like to add a flash message when the user is redirected to the login page for the first time (something like "Login to see this page").

I am not sure what would be the best approach. I think that the redirection is triggered by `ExceptionListener::startAuthentication`. The second argument of this method is an exception (`AuthenticationException $authException`), that is probably set to something when the user is trying to access a protected page while being anonymous.

Can I somehow override this behavior and add a flash message or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use "before and after" filters explained in the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

I think this is a good approach for your case.